# Не работает Queue в Google Colab

Tags: python, очередь, multiprocessing

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что приведенный ниже код нормально работает в pycharm, но его никак не получается запустить в Google Colab. Не происходит добавления передаваемого элемента в очередь в функции worker. Буду благодарен если подскажете)

import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def worker(q, f):
q.put(f)

if **name** == '**main**':
output_queue = mp.Queue()

```
p = mp.Process(target=worker, args=(output_queue, 5))
p.start()

while True:
    if not output_queue.empty():  
        msg = output_queue.get() 
        print(msg)
    else:
        time.sleep(3)

p.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def worker(q, f):
    q.put(f)
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    output_queue = mp.Queue()

    p = mp.Process(target=worker, args=(output_queue, 5))
    p.start()

    while True:
        if not output_queue.empty():  
            msg = output_queue.get() 
            print(msg)
        else:
            time.sleep(3)

    p.join()
```